# Flutter Local Notification using Timestamp

Tags: flutter, dart, localnotification

I am trying to schedule notification through timestamp.
I am using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) for local notification.

```
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';

void showNotification() async {
      // converting timestamp to DateTime
       var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1615463999 * 1000);  
       print(date); // 2021-03-11 17:29:59.000 (My Local time when the notification is to be shown)

    
    final String currentTimeZone =
        await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();

    final location = tz.getLocation(currentTimeZone);
    // print(currentTimeZone); // Asia/Kolkata
    // print(location); // Asia/Kolkata (It also provides same output)
    
   //converting DateTime to TimeZone format(as per doc of local notification)
    var time2 = tz.TZDateTime.from(date, location);
    print(time2); //2021-03-11 17:29:59.000+0530
    
    var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'id',
      'channel ',
      'description',
      priority: Priority.high,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
    );
    var iOS = IOSNotificationDetails();
    final NotificationDetails platform =
        NotificationDetails(android: android, iOS: iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(0, 'Flutter devs',
        'Flutter Local Notification Demo', time2, platform,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
```

The notification never appears. Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you didn't set schedule correctly

Comment: can you please correct me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.